# NuxtJS Configuration: Cannot get plugins to register with application when sourced from node_modules

Tags: npm, webpack, nuxt.js

## Premise

I have multiple sites with similar NuxtJS based architecture and am working on generalizing code they depend on by moving it into a self-hosted npm repository.

Currently all sites have a typical nuxt directory structure in regards to plugins.

`mySite1` structure

```
/.nuxt
/assets
/components
/layouts
/middleware
/modules
/node_modules
/pages
/plugins
   myPlugin1.js
   myPlugin2.js
/static
/store
...
...
```

in `mySite1/nuxt.config.js`, I register these plugins like so:

```
...
plugins: [
   '~/plugins/myPlugin1.js',
   '~/plugins/myPlugin2.js'
]
...
```

example of `myPlugin*.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import SomeDependency from 'some-dependency'

Vue.use(SomeDependency)
```

These `myPlugin*.js` files are duplicated in every site's (mySite1, mySite2, etc) repo, so in order to wrangle that I want to move them into my npm package (myPackage), but these plugins fail to register when I reference their path.

## Desire:

`myPackage` structure

```
plugins/
   myPlugin1.js
   myPlugin2.js
```

`mySite1/nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: [
   '~/node_modules/myPackage/plugins/myPlugin1.js',
   '~/node_modules/myPackage/plugins/myPlugin2.js'
]
```

## Issue:

For some reason I can't identify, none of the plugins from `myPackage` are being registered, and I'm looking for reasons why.

A few notes:

- I actually got this to work on one site, but it failed on the next two I tried to generalize. This is odd, and making me think there could be some kind of race condition in nuxt's build. I am transpiling `myPackage` in `nuxt.config.js`

```
...
build: {
      transpile: [
        'myPackage'
      ],
...
```

- For those that are familiar with working with self-hosted packages, when I run `npm link myPackage` (which symlinks to my working dir of `myPackage` instead of the one in `node_modules`), it also works.

This has to either be a nuxt build thing I can't get around, or a webpack configuration thing I can't identify. I realize this is a bit abstract, but the amount of setup it would take to make a reproduction and for anyone wanting to try this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. `myPackage` had `Vue` as a dependency, as did `MySite1`, `MySite2`, etc. NPM will look for a dependency in the `node_modules` folder if the project it's currently executing code in before going up the chain, so the `Vue` that `Vue.use` was referencing was the wrong `Vue`.

Moral of the story, only install Vue in one place. In my case, that meant removing Vue as a dependency of `myPackage`.